# Apache PDFBox 1.6.0 TextStripper not able to recognise characters having "Frutiger LT - 45" fonts

Tags: eclipse, apache, pdfbox

When I tried to extract contents from PDFs, I am successfully able to extract all text with PDFBox API but getting trouble with fonts having 'Frutiger' style. For these I am getting squared Boxes in place of characters.

It seems PDFBox FontBox supports only 14 UTF characters set, [see link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/workingwithfonts.html). And none of them is Frutiger style fonts.  Is this a BUG with PDFBox or I am missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure the characters are not just Unicode characters that can't be displayed by whatever you are using to look at them? Non-displayable characters are often shown as boxes.

Comment: Please supply a sample pdf to verify. Furthermore pdfbox 1.60 is a very old version. Update at least to an 1.8.x Version.

Comment: Hi greg- Yes I am pretty sure because I can read the text in my PDF.

Comment: Hi mkl - Yes you are right that PDFBox version that i am using is quite old but it has been used in my PDF comparator tool and I am just improving the same. And for using PDFBox 1.8.x version what I can see in their link that though it is upgraded but still it doesn't support "Frutiger" font styles. I didnot come across any other issues while using the old version other than this font issue. Also as I am working on a clint end tool and using their production PDF's which uses this font style so I cannot supply the sample PDF for that.very sorry for that. COuld you suggest any other work around?

Comment: Thanks a lot to greg and mkl to looking into this on a New year eve!! really appreciate your support...